# Allow Line Breaks in a php chat - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, chat, line-breaks

I built a very simple chat system... it works great and when the user enters a message it displays properly, the only problem is that line breaks don't show up.... somewhere along the line of sending the info to the database and retrieving it I lose the line breaks...

I am thinking I need to convert `\n` to `<br>` somewhere along the way but I really don't know much about this type of coding... I've mostly done games and stuff... No websites or database coding until today (my first day)

Here is my code found on chat.php

```
<html><head></head><body>
<form action="chat.php" method="post">
Message: <br><textarea type="text" name="message" style="width:80%; height:300px;"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<div style="width:100%;">

<?php

$host="***";
$user="***";
$password="***";

$cxn = mysql_pconnect ($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db("defaultdb", $cxn);

if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
    $ipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
} else {
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

$message = strip_tags($_POST["message"]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ChatTest (ID, TimeStamp, Message) VALUES ('$ipaddress', NOW(), '$message')");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3 width='100%' style='table-layout:fixed'>
        "; 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th style='width:10%;'>ID:</th><th style='width:10%;'>TimeStamp:</th><th style='width:70%;'>Message:</th>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
 Print "
        <tr>"; 
    Print " <td>".$info['ID'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$info['TimeStamp'] . " </td>";
    Print " <td style='white-space:pre-wrap;white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;white-space:-pre-wrap;white-space:-o-pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word'>".$info['Message'] . "</td></tr>
            "; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 

mysql_close($cxn);


?>

</div></body></html>
```

Comment: You really need to enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - you have quite a bunch of issues in your code, e.g. unquoted strings.

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling

Comment: your getenv calls are wrong. they're looking up undefined constants, which PHP might, on a good day, politely translate to a string for you. they should be `getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')` to be correct.

Comment: Actually they shouldn't be `getenv` calls at all but a simple `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. And `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` **cannot be trusted** - when not behind a proxy the user can set it to *anything*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert plain linebreaks to html linebreaks.